# USIM unable to store contact

Tags: contacts

Using Jellybean (4.4.2) I'm trying to save a new contact to my phone (I want to whatsapp this person).

Whether I add the person through my `People` app or through Whatsapp itself, I get the same error:

> The USIM is unable to store the contact

I have only 72 contacts and it's my understanding that USIM allows for thousands so what gives?

Comment: The details you want to store? SIMs were not intended to keep so many of them per person as we use today. Usually, a SIM contact consists of not much more than a name and a *single* number – no multiple numbers, no mail addresses, no Skype user names, etc.

Comment: @Izzy it's a new contact so just the name and a single phone number...

Comment: OK, then I don't know what it could be. I no longer store contacts to SIM.

Comment: To Google rather?